# Set with infinitely many limit points not contained in S

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I'm trying to find a set S with infinitely many limit points but none of the limit points themselves can be contained in S.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example

$$S = \left\lbrace k + \frac{1}{n} : k,n \in \mathbb N \text{ and } n \geq 3 \right\rbrace $$

Answer (score 1):

Another answer gave an unbounded set as an example, but you can assume the set is bounded by modifying it to

$$S = \{2^{-k} + 2^{-n} \, | \, n > k + 1 \geq 1, k,n \in {\mathbb Z}\}$$

Comment: Did you put $n>k+1$ with a reason? When I was looking at your set, I thought we could write it as $$S=\bigcup \limits_{k\ge 2} S_k\\ S_k:=\left\{2^{-k}+2^{-n}\mid n\in\Bbb N, n>k+1\right\}.$$

Comment: And I forgot to write, $S_i, S_j, i\ne j$ should, if I'm not wrong, be disjoint.